# Why use union to represent IP in IN6_ADDR

Tags: c, networking

I am learning networking on Windows using C. I came across `IN6_ADDR` structure that represents an IPv6 address as a union of 2 arrays:

```
typedef struct in6_addr {
  union {
    UCHAR  Byte[16];
    USHORT Word[8];
  } u;
} IN6_ADDR, *PIN6_ADDR, *LPIN6_ADDR;
```

I can't wrap my head around why would someone desire a union of 2 arrays instead of just 1 array. What is the reason for such declaration? Note that both arrays are 128 bits long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPv6 addresses are generally written in a format that uses 2-byte groups, e.g.

```
2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
```

Each of those groups corresponds to an element of the `Word` array.

But sometimes it's also useful to process each byte of the address. In this case, you would use the `Byte` array, rather than having to shift and mask elements of `Word`.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 addresses are typically represented as a group of 16-bit values, for example:

2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334

The `Word` member allows you to read these 16 bit words individually instead of reading a single byte at a time.